# Cual es la version de angular que tengo instalada?

Tags: angular

[image: No me sale la version de angular q tengo instalada en mi pc]

Estoy tratando de saber que version de angular tengo isntalada en mi laptop pero no me sale esa informacion

Answer (score 9):

Hola que tal puedes probar usando el comando:

```
ng version
```

Pero debes de ejecutarlo dentro de un directoria que contenga angular (Ejemplo alguno de tus proyectos) ya que ese comando necesita el packages.config

Espero te ayude.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos a partir de unas definiciones.

> **[Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/)**: Es una herramienta para inicializar, desarrollar, automatizar y mantener aplicaciones Angular.
>
> **[Angular](https://angular.io/)**: Es una plataforma de desarrollo para crear aplicaciones web móviles y de escritorio utilizando Typescript/JavaScript y otros lenguajes.

Tomando en cuenta lo anterior *Angular CLI* se instala como un comando (`ng`) para ser utilizado en la consola y que permite agilizar el proceso de crear una aplicación Angular.

Una vez que creaste tu aplicación con el comando `ng create my-app` en este caso *Angular CLI v6.2.5* creará una aplicación con *Angular v6.1.0*

Te recomiendo que te pases por el tutorial de iniciación de Angular:

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Y si necesitas más información de Angular CLI puedes consultar el siguiente enlace:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki

Comment: Si alguien me pasa un proyecto en Angular4 y yo tengo instalado Angular 6? hay algun problema?

Comment: Si ambos proyectos manejan la misma estructura/configuración (archivo `angular.json`) no habrá mayor problema más que los cambios que existan entre versiones. Tal vez valdría la pena formular una nueva pregunta para responder adecuadamente.

Answer (score 2):

Con el comando `ng version` en cmd, estando dentro de tu proyecto con angular
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes tener varias versiones de Angular al mismo tiempo, o mejor dicho **puedes tener más de un proyecto Angular cada uno con una versión diferente**, por eso no te aparece al usar `ng --version` pero si la de ***Angular CLI*** que es una aplicación que tienes instalada en *Node*, y tiene una versión determinada.

Para saber la **versión de Angular** usada en una aplicación Angular: ve a la carpeta del proyecto y abre el fichero "package.json", busca "dependencies". Te encontrarás con algo como esto:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "ngx-i18nsupport": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
```

Con la consulta anterior tienes la información más detallada. Ahora, si quieres conocer la versión Angular del proyecto, de forma general, en el mismo directorio donde se encuentra este fichero el comando `ng --version` ahora tiene acceso a la configuración de Angular, del proyecto actual, y ahora si, te va a indicar la versión:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]